# SQL distributed transaction. Problem with getting data from SQL VIEW

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm an Microsoft SQL VIEW's end-user on SQL 2000.

Up to now I'm using Excel Microsoft Query to fetching data. It works properly.

I've decided to improve my work and rearange working with this VIEW.

I wrote python script that should fetch data, do some calculation, export to Excel and send it to many recipients.
But python script is having a problem with getting data, showing me an error:

> The operation could not be performed because the OLE DB provider 'SQLOLEDB' was unable to begin a distributed transaction. (7391) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server][OLE/DB provider returned message: New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator. ] (7312); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'SQLOLEDB' ITransactionJoin::JoinTransaction returned 0x8004d00a]. (7300)`

Excel connection works proper only python script not working.

Python script is quite simple and works with other VIEWs placed on this server.

```
connectionString = f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD};WSID={WSID};APP={APP}'
conn=pyodbc.connect(connectionString)

sql = 'SELECT * FROM VIEW_DATA'
conn_cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
sql_data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Maybe someone have similar problem and solved it?

It make me crazy that Excel works but python not.

Comment: Do you mean your code would work better if you selected from a base table?

Comment: No. It would work as good as now, but right now I have to refresh data in Excel, drop not needed rows and then send it to recipients. Python script should do this without my participation.

Comment: You do know that SQL Server 2000 ran out of support *well over* a decade ago; right? You really need to work out an upgrade path, which is going to be *incredibly* different, as no supported version of SQL Server support restoring a database directly from SQL Server 2000. The "newest" version that did, if I recall correctly, is SQL Server 2008, which ran *completely* out of support almost *5* years ago. As a result, you likely would need to script out everything and address any breaking changes; which to a modern version is likely to be numerours.

Comment: I'm just a man working with numbers in finance not an IT guy ;) I'm fully aware of age and suport for SQL 2000, but what I can do? I now that SQL 2000 is linked with another MS SQL (I've no idea what version or so). This VIEW is getting data from both of this SQL Servers.

Comment: SQL 2000? hahahahaahah. Comedy aside. why are you trying to perform a  distributed transaction?

Comment: @MitchWheat As I just said, I'm end-user this VIEW. It' wasn't me that create this VIEW. I think DT preforms because to SQL 2000 is linked another MS SQL. Results of this VIEW are datas from two MS SQL. I'm just working with this set of tools and trying to make my work easier.

Comment: Try using autocommit=True when creating connection perhaps. Just a guess but perhaps pyodbc starts some transaction which sql server 2000 doesn't like.

Comment: Btw, there was an article about some german trains running windows 3.11. Sometimes one gotta work with what one has!

Comment: @MitchWheat Wouldn't this question be best migrated to [retrocomputing.se].....?

Comment: @siggemannen You are genius. It works. I've spent over a month (with break of course) on finding a solution. And here it is. Thank you very much.!!!!

Comment: That you are working in finance and using such an old version is even more terrifying. That version is simply *not* secure, and therefore so too is all of your client's financial data.

Comment: @AndrzejGorczyński glad it worked for you! =) In my opinion, defaulting to autocommit=False was a mistake by pyodbc developers

Answer (score 1):

As @siggemannen

> Try using **autocommit=True** when creating connection perhaps. Just a guess but perhaps pyodbc starts some transaction which sql server 2000 doesn't like.